# How has foreign admissions to US colleges and educational institutions fared since Trump's appointment?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, education

U.S. President Donald Trump is interested in significant changes to US education and immigration policy. Trump and his cabinet have lauded policies which would [reduce the government's role in university education](https://www.washingtonpost.com/local/education/trumps-first-full-education-budget-deep-cuts-to-public-school-programs-in-pursuit-of-school-choice/2017/05/17/2a25a2cc-3a41-11e7-8854-21f359183e8c_story.html?utm_term=.b4d41700b91f) and [reduce legal immigration](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/08/02/us/politics/trump-immigration.html).

How has admissions of foreign students to US schools changed since Trump was elected? Have these policies led to any change in the profile of students being admitted?

Comment: On one hand, it's an interesting question. On the other hand, it is useless **as worded** because correllation!=causation, and I doubt it's possible to establish causation from just one data point (in other words, **admissions aren't related to politics**, precisely because **you didn't establish causative relation with politics** a-priori). One question that COULD be on-topic AND answerable, imho, would be to ask if any polls of students tracked decision to attend/not attend based on Trump. I'm not aware of such a poll but i one exist it WOULD be a good answer.

Comment: I edited your question. I think it was only a hair's-breadth away from being a great on topic question, so I attempted to articulate what I think you were interested in. I also anchored it to education policy, which is on topic.  You can revert my edits or edit more if I am off base.

Comment: @user4012: its a question and not an answer, an answer may 'establish causative relation with politics'; then again, it might not.

Comment: IMO you're asking too early. The election occurred after the 2017-2018 school/university year, so you're unlikely to get anything meaningful by observing this year's data. Try next year to see if there's any trend.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy: that's a possibility, but if there was a systematic change across schools/colleges then surely thats a useful data-point in itself given just how many there would be?

Comment: @MoziburUllah: It's unlikely there's anything to see. Parents usually move in the summer, and university students typically plan spending time in foreign universities well in advance.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy I understand most schools' admissions deadlines are after November, so this year could be effected by perceptions or expectations. Perhaps this is better placed at academia.se

Comment: We had a [question very similar to this](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/24871/is-usa-gradually-losing-its-popularity-among-international-students) just the other day..

Answer (score 1):

Other than some of the issues brought up in the comments (correlation/causation):

1. Trump hasn't been president for more than a year, so it would be hard to prove anything absolutely at this point.  We can look at the trend over time to see if that has changed, but less than one year?
2. [This article](https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2017/03/13/nearly-4-10-universities-report-drops-international-student-applications) indicates that 40% of unis have seen reduced foreign enrollment and the article attempts to prove this is related to the political climate.
3. [In 2014, the number of international students had been climbing](https://www.usnews.com/education/best-colleges/articles/2014/11/17/number-of-international-college-students-continues-to-climb).
4. We should consider that tuition also rose that year overall, and [according to the WSJ](https://www.wsj.com/articles/in-reversal-colleges-rein-in-tuition-1500822001), 2017 was one of the few years tuition didn't see a huge increase due in tuition.  Are non-Americans willing to pay for an expensive education, when they can get a comparable one elsewhere at reduced cost?  I don't know the answer, but price could be a factor.  Either way, the WSJ points to reduced enrollments.
5. I know many Americans who've been questioning the value of US university education.  At what point do non-Americans start to ask this as well?  I can't answer on this, but if Americans are questioning their own universities (unrelated to Trump), it's possible non-Americans might for similar reasons.

This doesn't mean Trump won't negatively impact American universities; I think it's a little too early to tell right now and the trends we're seeing may be related more to price (per WSJ) and quality (WSJ and IHE).